# Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, android-studio, gradle

Build file 'C:\Progress Presentation\dracula\android\build.gradle' line: 16

Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.3.15', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.3.15', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.gms.google-services:com.google.gms.google-services.gradle.plugin:4.3.15')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:238)

Tried Solutions:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.+'
```

Please add google-services.json in your app folder.